# Gradle task 'assembleDebug' error for flutter project

Tags: gradle, flutter

Trying flutter for the first time. Going as per the official documentation, cannot start the app.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode... Initializing gradle...                                       0.8s Resolving dependencies...                                   11.9s Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                   

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/droid/AndroidUbuntu/androidSdkUbuntu/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip''
```

I face the same issue using the `flutter run` on terminal or using *create a new flutter project* using Android Studio.

Don't know if this is gradle specific or a flutter issue.

Comment: solved the issue with the help of https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5487; simply rename or delete the ndk-bundle as explained.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually [an issue](https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-gradle-runner/issues/57#issuecomment-389136888) that was encountered using the latest android linux stack's Android NDk version during that time.

Numerous workaround could resolve the issue including the solution in the [GitHub thread](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5487#issuecomment-340407910) comment section.

Here is another related GitHub post that exhibits the same issue. In the thread, it mentioned that that they've updated the android linux stack's Android NDk version to the latest: [r17](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history).

You can follow [this guide](https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/how-to-install-a-specific-android-ndk-version-on-the-android-linux-stack/4400) mentioned in the GitHub post to install any Android stack version that you will be needing.

Comment: Thanks, already solved it as mentioned in my comment to the question. +1